# Stop receiving user input for Arraylist when negative number is entered with while loop

Tags: loops, arraylist, while-loop

Im currently making a program which adds user input to an arrayList called score, and when a negative number is entered, it breaks from the while loop.

I currently have my attempt of the code, however i am currently having issues with the boolean operators in my else-if statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab03_Part_1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double sum;
        double avg;
        int i;
        boolean acceptableScore = true;
        List<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (acceptableScore) 
        {
                                                                                                                            
            if ((score >= 0) && (score <= 100)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Student Score: ");
                score.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }
            else if (score > 100) 
            {
                System.out.println("that is not an acceptable Score");
            }
            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the current error i get.

```
The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) List<Integer>, int
    The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) List<Integer>, int
    The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) List<Integer>, int
```

From what i understand of this error message, the main issue is that i am using Integer while creating my ArrayList, however boolean requires int? I am very new to coding so this issue is new territory for me.

Im not looking for someone to code this for me, but i would really appreciate any help someone can provide, thank you.

Comment: `score` is a list of integer you can't compare any value with list. You can do list `score.get(index) >= 0` means element of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

You are directly adding the user input to ArrayList.

### What you should do:

Store the input in a variable, perform checks on it and act accordingly.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab03_Part_1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double sum;
        double avg;
        int s;
        boolean acceptableScore = true;
        List<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (acceptableScore) 
        {
            s = scanner.nextInt();
            if ((s >= 0) && (s <= 100)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Student Score:");
                score.add(s);
            }
            else if (s > 100) 
            {
                System.out.println("that is not an acceptable Score");
            }
            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```